# python : parse table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a table from this website: [personal.vanguard.com](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FundsAllHoldings?FundId=0970&FundIntExt=INT&tableName=Equity&tableIndex=0&sort=HOLDINGS_NAME&sortOrder=web.funds.profile.view.FundsAllHoldingsSort$SortOrder@35208480)

I'm trying to get *"Holdings"* and *"Market values"* columns.

I've tried that query but with no luck:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FundsAllHoldings?FundId=0970&FundIntExt=INT&tableName=Equity&tableIndex=0').read())
print(soup.prettify())

print soup('tbody')

table = soup.find("tbody", { "class" : "Holding" })

print table
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select all rows using this expression:

```
soup.select('tbody tr')
```

Then, for each row you could extract all columns:

```
[tr('td') for tr in soup.select('tbody tr')]

# Example output (note the first empty row):
[[],
 [<td align="left">zulily Inc. Class A</td>,
  <td>965,202</td>,
  <td class="nr">$12,750,318</td>],
 [<td align="left">xG Technology Inc.</td>,
  <td>34,385</td>,
  <td class="nr">$57,767</td>],
 [<td align="left">vTv Therapeutics Inc. Class A</td>,
  <td>80,223</td>,
  <td class="nr">$802,230</td>],
 [<td align="left">salesforce.com inc</td>,
  <td>11,014,606</td>,
  <td class="nr">$807,370,620</td>],
 [<td align="left">pSivida Corp.</td>,
  <td>447,326</td>,
  <td class="nr">$1,816,144</td>],
 [<td align="left">lululemon athletica Inc.</td>,
  <td>1,737,050</td>,
  <td class="nr">$109,190,963</td>]]
```

All you need is to filter required columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = 'https://personal.vanguard.com/us/FundsAllHoldings?FundId=0970&FundIntExt=INT&tableName=Equity&tableIndex=0'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
table = soup.find("tbody", { "class" : "right" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if len(cells) > 0: # skip first row
        holding = cells[0]
        mv = cells[2]
        print holding, mv
```